# 3GB RAM best configuration?

Tags: firefox, ram

I use Firefox and usually have around 15 tabs active.
The web pages are not very large,  usually on average 2-3MB.
However, if they have scripts the browser cannot handle the work and all resources become unavailable.
Often X-KILL is needed to completely shutdown the browser.

Steps I have taken:

using other browsers:  has not improved the situation.

clearing memory using the following commands:

```
sudo sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

This occasionally helps,  but usually I cannot access a terminal due to the system freeze.  By the time the system begins to free some memory to access the terminal, the web page is loading.

OS:  64 bit

CPU clock:
2.27GHz

swappiness configuration:
vm.swappiness = 42

output of free:

```
$ free -h
        total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:     2,6G        1,7G        235M        321M        690M        302M
Swap:    2,7G        2,3G        460M
```

Comment: Are you sure about your "3MB" ?  It doesn't seem much, and if each tab really take only 3MB that would not cause any major problem. Isn't it 300MB ?

Comment: I have statistics for the web page sizes when loading and they are usually under 4MB.  When scripts are included in the web page,  this slows the system down, and sometimes freezes the entire system for 5 minutes.  Perhaps I should look at other areas such as hard drive?

Comment: @LinuxUser2018 the fact your swap is almost completely consumed explains a lot.  You need to give more resources to the system and control the usage of resources on the system so that you **are not** using Swap as much.  Swap is there for overflow, yes, but it shouldn't be treated as 'extra RAM' because it is much slower than actual RAM, even on SSDs.  My opinion: you're overtaxing the system by using far too much of the system resources by almost a factor of three.  That's why your system is running so slowly and causing problems.  Firefox is also a memory whore, so you should...

Comment: ... ***close firefox tabs*** when you aren't using them and don't need to keep them open, since each tab will continue to be loaded into memory until you close them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the tabs open for continuous use of different resources.   When you suggest freeing the system, do you refer to swappiness?  What level do you recommend?

Comment: If you are going to have 15 tabs open in firefox, then you need about 4GB of RAM.

Comment: Your problem is due to insufficient RAM for what you want to do. You either need to reduce your ram use (less tabs) or buy more ram.

Comment: Buy more RAM. The amount of RAM required for a web page is not simply the size of the data transferred. The web browser is a virtual machine. If you want to use less RAM, you can disable scripts, plug-ins, extensions, and styling. However, you won't like using the web pages, I'm sure.

Comment: You can easily view the amount of ram for each tab by opening `System Monitor` and order by _Memory_. Each tab is a different _Web Content_ process (and is easily about at least 100MB).